# "textarea" en formulario que usa "useForm" y "register" no obtiene value del estado (useState)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

mi text area

```
id="textareaBio"
```

obtiene el valor de un estado

```
const [bio, setBio] = useState('');
```

que se actualiza mediante un evento onChange,

```
onChange: checkNoMoreThreeRows
```

todo funciona bien menos el hecho de que el text area no ve el valor

```
value: bio,
```

del estado y no se entera de lo que esta pasando, ya le he dado vueltas al asunto y no logro dar con lo que pasa. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useCallback, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Form, FormGroup, Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { UserContext } from 'context/UserContext';
import { FormDataContext } from 'context/FormDataContext';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

//helpers
import { commonNameSpacesLan, checkLoging, REDIRECT_TO_LOGING } from 'helpers';
/* Layouts */
import { MainLayoutChildren } from '@/components/layouts/MainLayoutChildren';
/* Componentes */
import Avatar from '@/components/avatar';
import { Tags } from '@/components/metaTags/tags';
import ChangePassword from '@/components/modals/ChangePassword';
/* translate */
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';
import { getProfilePublications, getUserPublications } from 'api/posts';
/* icons */
import ReactSpinner from 'react-bootstrap-spinner';
import { modifyAccount } from 'api/user';
//
import { showToast } from 'helpers';
//
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { AiFillCamera } from 'react-icons/ai';

//modal
import CropBannerImage from '@/components/modals/CropBannerImage';
import CropProfileImage from '@/components/modals/CropProfileImage';

export const editProfile = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('profile');
  const [dataUser, setDataUser] = useState({});
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [banner, setBanner] = useState('');
  const [bio, setBio] = useState('');
  const [previousBio, setPreviousBio] = useState('');
  const [textMaxLength, setTextMaxLength] = useState(1000000);
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
  } = useForm({ defaultValues: { name: '', last_name: '', phone: '', bio: '' } });
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState('');
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);

  const { dataForm, setDataForm } = useContext(FormDataContext);

  //Banner Modal
  const [changeBannerModal, setChangeBannerModal] = useState(false);
  const toggleBannerProfile = () => {
    setChangeBannerModal(!changeBannerModal);
  };
  const onClickSaveBanner = (e) => {
    setBanner(e.src);
  };

  //Image Modal
  const [changeImageModal, setChangeImageModal] = useState(false);
  const toggleImageProfile = () => {
    setChangeImageModal(!changeImageModal);
  };
  const onClickSavePhoto = (e) => {
    setPhoto(e.src);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateData = {
      name: user.name,
      last_name: user.last_name,
      phone: user.phone,
      bio: user.bio,
    };
    reset(updateData);
    setDataProfile(user);
    setDataUser(user);
    setDataForm(dataUser);
  }, [user]);

  const setDataProfile = () => {};

  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    if (photo != '') {
      values.photo = photo;
    }
    if (banner != '') {
      values.banner = banner;
    }
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', values.name);
    formData.append('last_name', values.last_name);
    formData.append('phone', values.phone);
    formData.append('bio', values.bio);
    if (photo != '') {
      const blob = await fetch(values.photo).then((res) => res.blob());
      const file = new File([blob], 'filename.jpeg');
      formData.append('photo', file);
    }
    if (banner != '') {
      const blob = await fetch(values.banner).then((res) => res.blob());
      const file = new File([blob], 'filename.jpeg');
      formData.append('banner', file);
    }
    const { status, data } = await modifyAccount(user?.id, formData);
    if (status === 200) {
      setDataProfile(data.data);
      setDataUser(data.data);
      setUser(data.data);
      Cookies.set('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data.data));
      showToast('success', 'Actualizado correctamente.');
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIsOpen(true);
    } else {
      showToast('warning', 'Por favor intentelo de nuevo.');
      setIsOpen(true);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const openChangePassword = () => {
    setOpenModal(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenModal(false);
  };

  const validatePhoneNumberOnly = (e) => {
    var key = window.event ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  const checkNoMoreThreeRows = (e) => {
    console.log('entra');
    
    console.log(e);
    var content = e.target.value
    console.log(content);
    let lines = content.split('\n');
    console.log(lines.length)
    var lastLine = lines[lines.length - 1];
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var virtualComponent = canvas.getContext('2d');
    virtualComponent.font =
      'normal 16px system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"';
    var widthTextLastLine = virtualComponent.measureText(lastLine).width;
    var widthTextArea = document.getElementById('textareaBio').getBoundingClientRect().width - 32;

    if (lines.length > 3) {
      console.log('mas de 3 filas')
      if (lines.length > 4) {
        console.log('mas de 4 filas')
        console.log(previousBio)
        setBio(previousBio);
        return;
      }
      if (lines[3].length > 0) {
        setBio(previousBio);
        return;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var widthLine = virtualComponent.measureText(lines[i]).width;
        if (widthLine > widthTextArea) {
          setBio(previousBio);
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    if (widthTextLastLine > widthTextArea) {
      var indexLastSpace = content.lastIndexOf(' ');
      var lastContent = content.substr(indexLastSpace + 1);
      content = content.substr(0, indexLastSpace) + '\n';
      let linesCheck = content.split('\n');
      if (linesCheck.length < 4) {
        content = content + lastContent;
      }
    }
    console.log(content);
    setPreviousBio(content);
    setBio(content);
    //setDataForm({ ...dataForm, bio: content });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {user && (
        <MainLayoutChildren dataUser={dataUser} isMyProfile={true} isEdit={true}>
          <Tags>
            <title>{dataUser?.name + ' ' + dataUser?.last_name} - dioxas.com</title>
            <meta name="description" content={dataUser?.name + ' ' + dataUser?.last_name + ' perfil en dioxas.com'} />
            <meta
              property="og:title"
              content={dataUser?.name + ' ' + dataUser?.last_name + ' - dioxas.com'}
              key="title"
            />
            <meta name="keywords" content={dataUser?.name + ' ' + dataUser?.last_name + ' perfil en dioxas.com'} />
          </Tags>
          <Container>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <br />
              <p>Foto de portada</p>
              <FormGroup>
                <div className="file-input-banner">
                  {/* <input
                    id="file-banner"
                    name="file-banner"
                    type="file"
                    className="input-file-photo"
                    accept=".png, .jpeg"
                    // onChange={(event) => {
                    //   setBanner(event.currentTarget.files[0]);
                    // }}
                  /> */}
                  <div className="jc-center-alitems-center full-width">
                    {banner != '' ? (
                      <label className="label-cover" onClick={() => toggleBannerProfile()}>
                        {/* <canvas className={'user-cover-photo-img'} ref={banner} /> */}
                        <img className={'user-cover-photo-img'} src={banner} />
                      </label>
                    ) : dataUser?.banner ? (
                      <label className="label-cover" onClick={() => toggleBannerProfile()}>
                        <img className={'user-cover-photo-img'} src={dataUser?.banner} />
                      </label>
                    ) : (
                      <label className="label-cover" onClick={() => toggleBannerProfile()}>
                        <div className="user-cover-photo-img user-cover-photo-default"></div>
                      </label>
                    )}
                    <label className="label-cover-text" onClick={() => toggleBannerProfile()}>
                      <p className="user-editar-cover">
                        {' '}
                        <AiFillCamera className="icon_cam" /> Subir foto de portada
                      </p>
                    </label>
                    <CropBannerImage
                      isOpen={changeBannerModal}
                      setBanner={(event) => {
                        onClickSaveBanner(event);
                      }}
                      toggleModal={toggleBannerProfile}
                      onClick={() => toggleBannerProfile()}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                {errors.banner && <small className="text-danger">{t('inputError')}</small>}
              </FormGroup>
              <br />
              <p>Foto de perfil</p>
              <FormGroup>
                <div className="file-input">
                  <input
                    id="file"
                    name="file"
                    type="file"
                    className="input-file-photo"
                    accept=".png, .jpeg"
                    onChange={(event) => {
                      setPhoto(event.currentTarget.files[0]);
                    }}
                  />
                  <div className="jc-center-alitems-center full-width">
                    {photo != '' ? (
                      <label onClick={() => toggleImageProfile()}>
                        {/* <Avatar
                          width="4rem"
                          height="4rem"
                          url={URL.createObjectURL(photo)}
                          username={dataUser?.username}
                        /> */}
                        <img
                          style={{ width: '80px', height: '80px', borderRadius: '50%' }}
                          className={'icon-avatar'}
                          src={photo}
                        />
                        {/* <Avatar url={URL.createObjectURL(photo)} username={dataUser?.username}  width="60" height="60"/> */}
                      </label>
                    ) : (
                      <Fragment>
                        {dataUser?.photo != '' ? (
                          <label onClick={() => toggleImageProfile()}>
                            <img
                              style={{ width: '80px', height: '80px', borderRadius: '50%' }}
                              className={'icon-avatar'}
                              src={dataUser?.photo}
                            />
                          </label>
                        ) : (
                          <label style={{ paddingBottom: '2rem' }} onClick={() => toggleImageProfile()}>
                            <Avatar width="80px" height="80px" url={dataUser?.photo} username={dataUser?.username} />
                          </label>
                        )}
                      </Fragment>
                    )}
                    <CropProfileImage
                      isOpen={changeImageModal}
                      setBanner={(event) => {
                        onClickSavePhoto(event);
                      }}
                      toggleModal={toggleImageProfile}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                {errors.photo && <small className="text-danger">{t('inputError')}</small>}
              </FormGroup>

              <FormGroup>
                <label className="edit-profile-label">
                  Nombres
                  <input
                    className="input-round"
                    defaultValue={dataUser?.name}
                    placeholder="Nombres"
                    {...register('name', { required: true, maxLength: 250 })}
                  />
                </label>
                {errors.name && <small className="text-danger">{t('inputError')}</small>}
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup>
                <label className="edit-profile-label">
                  Apellidos
                  <input
                    className="input-round"
                    defaultValue={dataUser?.last_name}
                    placeholder="Apellidos"
                    {...register('last_name', { required: true, maxLength: 250 })}
                  />
                </label>
                {errors.lastname && <small className="text-danger">{t('inputError')}</small>}
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup>
                <label className="edit-profile-label">
                  Teléfono
                  <input
                    className="input-round"
                    defaultValue={dataUser?.phone}
                    placeholder="Teléfono"
                    type="text"
                    maxLength={8}
                    onKeyPress={validatePhoneNumberOnly}
                    {...register('phone', { required: false })}
                  />
                </label>
                {errors.phone && <small className="text-danger">{t('inputErrorPhone')}</small>}
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup>
                <label className="edit-profile-label">
                  Bio
                  <textarea
                    id="textareaBio"
                    placeholder="Bio"
                    className="input-round-textarea"
                    autoCorrect="off"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    type="text"
                    defaultValue={dataUser?.bio}
                    //onKeyUp={(e) => checkNoMoreThreeRows(bio, e)}
                    rows={1}
                    {...register('bio', {
                      required: false,
                      maxLength: textMaxLength,
                      value: bio,
                      //onChange: (e) => setBio(e.target.value)
                      onChange: checkNoMoreThreeRows
                    })}
                  />
                </label>
                {errors.bio && <small className="text-danger">{t('inputErrorBio')}</small>}
              </FormGroup>
              <div className="edit-profile-div-buttons" style={{ display: 'none' }}>
                <button className="button-orange margin-top-10" type="submit" isSingleElement="true" id="saveButton">
                  Guardar
                  {isLoading && (
                    <div style={{ marginLeft: '.5rem' }}>
                      <ReactSpinner type="border" size={1} />
                    </div>
                  )}
                </button>
              </div>
            </Form>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
              <button onClick={() => openChangePassword()} className="button-orange" style={{}}>
                Cambiar contraseñaa
              </button>
            </div>
          </Container>
        </MainLayoutChildren>
      )}
      <ChangePassword isOpen={openModal} setModal={setOpenModal} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default editProfile;

export async function getServerSideProps({ locale, ...rest }) {
  try {
    if (!checkLoging(rest.req, rest.res)) return REDIRECT_TO_LOGING;

    return {
      props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [...commonNameSpacesLan, 'profile'])),
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontré el problema, la prpiedad value

```
value={bio}
```

no estaba en el lugar correcto:

```
<label className="edit-profile-label">
              Bio
              <textarea
                id="textareaBio"
                placeholder="Bio"
                className="input-round-textarea"
                autoCorrect="off"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                style={{ fontFamily: 'inherit', display: 'block' }}
                type="text"
                defaultValue={dataUser?.bio}
                value={bio}
                rows={1}
                {...register('bio', {
                  required: false,
                  maxLength: textMaxLength,
                  onChange: checkNoMoreThreeRows,
                })}
              />
            </label>
```